# How to added Blazor (client side) to existing ASP.NET Core (server side) or ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I already have a project with ASP.NET Core and I want to use it as a server side and add a client side to it to have a spa and create it as PWA for mobile

Comment: You can add it by right clicking on solution and add Blazor Client(Web Assembly) project template. You need to do some research before selecting this path. Specially on how to cover security into Blazor Client app.

Comment: I did not find a good source. Introduce a clear source